# Correlation bounds in terms of spectral radius

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, mutual-information, correlation-matrix

My application requires that the following is true for random variables $X$, $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $E[X]=0, E[Y]=0$ and spectral radius $\rho$
$$\rho(E[XX]^{-1}E[XY]E[YY]^{-1}E[YX])<0.5$$

Can something be said about the strength of correlation between $X$ and $Y$ for this to be true?

Clarifying notation above:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
E[XX]_{ij}&=&E[X_i X_j]\\
E[XY]_{ij}&=&E[X_i Y_j]\\
E[YX]_{ij}&=&E[Y_i X_j]\\
E[YY]_{ij}&=&E[Y_i Y_j]\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I cannot find any consistent way to make sense of this expression.  I understand that by "multivariate" you mean $X$ is some $n$ vector and $Y$ is some $m$ vector, but no matter whether I require $m=n$ or not and no matter whether I consider either or both to be column vectors or row vectors, the sequence of matrices implied by these four expectations cannot be multiplied except for special values of $m$ and $n.$  Please, then, clarify the meaning of your notation. Did you perhaps forget to indicate transposes in some places?

Comment: clarified notation above

Comment: Thanks.  Evidently $X$ and $Y$ have the same number of components.  By "spectral radius" do you therefore mean the largest absolute eigenvalue of the matrix formed componentwise by these four products?  Or are you forming the product of four matrices?

Comment: BTW, offering a simple example might help.  It strikes me that when all four expectations exist and the variables are in one dimension, the spectral radius can be made as close to $1$ as one would like, with no additional assumptions on $X$ and $Y.$  Would that be correct, or am I missing something in your notation or assumptions?

Comment: It's matrix multiplication (so they don't need to have same number of components). This is the same form as generalized version of "variance/covariance inequality", we know that that $<1$ is true by Schur's complement, tightening to 0.5 is more strict

Comment: Okay -- but consider what happens to your inequality when you add the same large constant to all components of $X$ and $Y.$ Notice that this won't change any of the correlation coefficients between components of $X$ and components of $Y.$  Indeed, in light of the fact there are $mn$ such pairs of components, could you be more specific about what you mean by "strength of correlation"?

Comment: You are right, I needed another assumption about variables being centered at 0

Comment: I don't know what is "the strength of correlation", that's basically the question. I have a requirement on spectral radius, which is opaque, and I'm looking to translate it into something easier to interpret. Maybe a bound on mutual information between two variables, or bound on largest correlation between any pair of components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quantity seems to have an interpretation in terms of top canonical correlation, from 19.7 of Matrix Tricks for Linear Statistical Models: Our Personal Top Twenty 2011th edition,

[image]

[image]